# Overlay not showing above Capacitor Camera Preview in Android (Vue js + Ionic)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, vuejs3, capacitor-plugin

I am trying to initiate `capacitor-community/camera-preview` plugin with Vue 3 (JS) and Ionic 6. I have followed all the solutions suggested in many other threads. Nothing has solved my issue.
When I try **toBack: true** option, no camera preview is showing. When I set it to *false*, only camera preview is showing. No overlay is displayed. The app is working as expected in the web browser. But, when I tried with the Android emulator, I have this issue.

Here is my Vue Component.

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-content :fullscreen="true">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="my-overlay">
          <h2>Overlay Text</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
  import { IonContent, IonPage, } from "@ionic/vue";
  import { Plugins } from "@capacitor/core";
  export default {
    name: "CameraPreview",
    components: { IonPage, IonContent },
    data() {
      return {
        imageSrc: '',
      };
    },

    mounted() {
      this.startCamera();
    },
    methods: {
     async startCamera() {
        await Plugins.CameraPreview.start({
          parent: "content",
          position: "rear",
          className: "content-camera-preview",
          toBack: true
        });
      }
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
ion-content {
   --background: transparent !important;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.my-overlay{
  color: red;
  z-index: 12;
  position: absolute;
  top:30%;
  left:4;
}
.content-camera-preview {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

</style>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --skip-plugins @vue/cli-plugin-eslint",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --skip-plugins @vue/cli-plugin-eslint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor-community/camera-preview": "^1.2.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.3.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.7",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.3.3",
    "@capacitor/filesystem": "^1.0.6",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.0",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.6",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.3",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.0.2",
    "@ionic/vue": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^6.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bulma": "^0.9.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "dom-to-image-more": "^2.8.0",
    "mitt": "^3.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.21",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.3.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.16",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.3",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "cypress": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.5",
    "stylelint": "^14.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^24.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

I have added the following style to the main scss file.

```
ion-content {
  --background: transparent !important;
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks in advance to everyone who tries to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by finding the overlayed elements. Adding `--background: transparent !important;` to ion-content did not solve my issue. Finally, I have inserted transparent background color to the main parent div on App.vue does solve the issue.

App.vue

```html
#app {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Also, it is safe to add the following style to the global scss file.

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On desktop browsers `CameraPreview` creates a `video` element within the `parent` you have set in the `start` config object.

In WebView it either does something else or WebView can't handle the `video` element correctly. It also can't be placed and scaled with float precision* which makes it useless for responsive designs. So I came up with a workaround:

- hide the CameraPreviw behind the app with `toBack: true` and by applying `display: none` to the `parent` element
- use `captureSample()` to capture samples from the previews stream
- convert them to dataURL (via a `canvas` element)
- set the dataURL as source for an `img` element

You can place and scale the `img` element as you wish.

Unfortunately, this solution is not very performant. It works okayish for my use case but does not provide the UX I'd like to present to my users.

* I filed an issue about that in the plugin's repo: https://github.com/capacitor-community/camera-preview/issues/320

An additional note about placing the preview stream on Android:

The preview image will always be fullscreen, but you can define a mask that is being stamped out of that image with `width`, `height`, `x` and `y` in the config object.

So if you want to use my method, you have to know where your `img` element is (you can get the values with `getBoundingClientRect()` and use those values for the config object.

Otherwise you get any part of the preview (that might even be skewed), not the one the user would expect at that position.